# Fill progress bar with php value

Tags: php, jquery, css

I would like make some progress bar like this link :

http://www.metallicabyrequest.com/results.php?s=70

And I have this table with 3 columns and the progress bar should be fill with the value from third column :

http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/ensR2/

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Song Name</th>
                    <th>% Ballots w/ Song</th>
                    <th># Votes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($array as $element) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="name"><?php echo $element['name']; ?></td>
                <td>PROGRESS BAR WITH 3 TD VALUE PERCENT</td>
                <td><?php echo $element['votes']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Hope you can understand what i try to say, thanks for your help !

Comment: In fiddle, why do you have PHP variables just openly lying inside HTML markup?

Comment: Need more information. it looks like that link has "total ballots" you can use as a baseline for percentage .. in order to make a div the right width you'd have to know the max number, vs. the "votes" to calculate a percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a number of Total votes ($totalvotes) to work with, and the votes for this particular element ($element['votes']) you could use the following:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="name"><?php echo $element['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color:#000;color:#fff;width:<?PHP echo ($element['votes']/$totalvotes)*100; ?>%">
                  <?PHP echo floor(($element['votes']/$totalvotes)*100); ?>%
              </div>
            </td>
            <td><?PHP echo $element['votes']; ?></td>
        </tr>
```

though it seems like you still need to provide the data (sql or otherwise) to provide both the total ballots, and total ballots with this element as I don't think you want to generate a percentage based on votes for "this" ballot from what I can see. You may end up gathering separate ballot data ($totalBallots and $ballotsWithThisElement) to get your proper percentage.

Comment: Yep, I edited the question and the fiddle before your response for more info, thanks so much for your help, with that I can able to finish it.

Comment: Excellent. glad to be of help. Don't forget to mark the answer as your solution.